# Role verification in nestJs framework using passport-jwt

Tags: typescript, passport.js, nestjs

I implemented authentication strategy basing on that article: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication. But I would like to expand that JwtStrategy on checking roles. It would be easiest to just add checks for oles in `jwt.strategy.ts` as there is already taken user basing on JWT payload.

But I don't know how to pass additional argument to `validate` function.

What I would like to implement:

```
async validate(payload: JwtPayload, done: Function, role: string) {        
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);
    if (!user || user.role !== role) {
        return done(new UnauthorizedException(), false);
    }
    done(null, user);
}
```

but I don't know how I could pass additional `role` argument to that function. I am using decorator `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))` for enabling guard. What I would like to achieve is add there as an additional parameter `role` string and using it in JWTStrategy.

What is easiest way to implement that? Or do I need to implement two seperate guards?

EDIT: Actually I wasn't aware that AuthGuard automatically attach user to request. Solution was just simply implement RoleGuard from url pointed by @hdias2310. (https://docs.nestjs.com/guards)

Comment: You'd need two separate Guards.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will need to have another guard to make a role verification.

You can get an example of implementation in NestJS docs (https://docs.nestjs.com/guards), in the "Role-based authentication" section.

Comment: Works like a charm. The problem was that I wasn't aware that AuthGuard automatically attach user to request which then could be use by RoleGuard.

Comment: If you can mark my answer as correct, I will really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, I would like to point to [auth0.com](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-a-secure-api-with-nestjs-adding-role-based-access-control/) that has a good section about roles based authentication.